# How to merge multiple XML files located in different folder paths into one XML file in PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, merge

I have 3 XML files that are located in different project folder paths to be merged into one. 
For Eg:

```
$Xml1 = "C:\XmlFolder1\XmlList1.xml
$Xml2 = "C:\XmlFolder2\XmlList2.xml
$Xml3 = "C:\XmlFolder3\XmlList3.xml
```

I need these 3 xml files to be merged into one, say - $MainXml = MainXml.xml (i.e, $Xml1 + $Xml2 + $Xml3)

All the Xml files contain same attributes. 
For Eg: Sample Xml snippet

```
<Projects>
<Project>C:\Foldercommon\project1.vbproj</Project>
<Project>C:\Foldercommon\project2.vbproj</Project>
</Projects>
```

There is a common logic for xml in my functions that would be achieved using $MainXml.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! 
Ashish

Comment: Read here, maybe can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972264/merge-multiple-xml-files-into-one-using-powershell-2-0

Comment: @Christian: start-Automating's sample code is somewhat not clear and have no clue till what extent that code would work for me as I have 3 xml files (sharing the same set of nodes) located in different paths on a remote server and I need to merge them into one final xml.. Thanks for your help so far:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using this:

```
$content1 = Get-Content $xml1 | Sort-Object
$content2 = Get-Content $xml2 | Sort-Object
$content3 = Get-Content $xml3 | Sort-Object

$XmlContent = $content1 +$content2 +$content3
```

But being a novice to Powershell, eager to learn new best possible way of working with XML in PowerShell :)

Thanks a lot Christian for your help so far :)